How to create a hover card animation like GitHub landing page cards in ReactJS?
I'm looking to implement a hover card animation similar to the ones seen on GitHub's landing page. The green blob following the mouse on hover and change transform on hover. I'm working with ReactJS and wondering what would be the best approach or library to achieve this effect efficiently. Any insights, code examples, or suggested libraries would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!


React-Tilt should help you achieve this. You can give it a shot
